# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I got a register page on my website, The problem is that i started to get this errors:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined**

**Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length" register.php:1**

**Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"**

**Even without the last 2 errors (if i dont set the connection,content-length headers) i will get the first error.**

For my ajax functionality i am using this function:

```
function AjaxLoad(xhr, url, cfunc, syn, method, headers, params)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = cfunc; // This line take place on true/false

    xhr.open(method, url, syn);
    $.each(headers ,function(index, value){
        xhr.setRequestHeader(index, value);
    });
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

At my js code i am calling the function like that:

```
var headersObject = {"Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-length" : userCap.val().length, "Connection" : "close" };    

AjaxLoad(
    xhr,
    "../php/Ajax/captchaValidator.php",
    getResponse,
    false,
    "POST",
    headersObject,
    userCap.attr("name") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(userCap.val())
);
```

**AjaxLoad arguments explanation:**

1. xhr object
2. location
3. onreadystatechange handler
4. Synchronous(its not working even if i will pass true)
5. method
6. headers
7. key=value pair(I did test it so it get the right value)

**This is the getResponse function:**

> ```
> function getResponse(){
>         var strongEl = capCon.next();
>             if(xhr.responseText == "0"){
>                 if(strongEl.prop("tagName") == "STRONG"){
>                     strongEl.getReplace('<strong id="sE">קוד שגוי</strong>');
>                 }else{
>                     capCon.after('<strong id="sE">קוד שגוי</strong>').next();
>                 }
>                 bToSubmit = false;
>             }else{
>                 if(strongEl.prop("tagName") == "STRONG"){
>                     strongEl.remove();
>                 }
>             }
>     }
> ```

I test the network to see if the file **captchaValidator.php** is even get to the browser and i get status 200 everything seems ok.

I did test for right values, The code did worked before i dont know what changed, But this is the link to my website registration page [Link](http://phpliteral.zapto.org/users/register.php), If you press **send**, You can see (in chrome browser at the network tab) that all is ok, But i get the errors i mentioned at the console tab, If some one can please take a look i will be very thankful.

Comment: If you have `$` (jQuery), why are you not using `$.ajax`?

Comment: Where is `getResponse` defined? That's where your first error originates from

Comment: I didnt study ajax on jquery, So until than i am using js

Comment: I will update in a sec with the getResponse

Comment: I am testing now, I did remove the xhr argument, and pass the AjaxLoad function into the form.js file.

Comment: I was looking at the php code i cant think of anything that may couse this problem any idea?

Comment: This is a little off topic, but I just wanted to make sure you're aware that by passing `false` to the `syn` parameter, you're actually making the request *synchronous* instead of *asynchronous*. Seems like you're expecting `true` to mean *sync* in the `xhr.open()`, when in fact `true` means the *async*.

Comment: I know what i am doing, The resone for the false is becouse i want the script to wait, So the getResponse can affect some variable, This variable is tested before the form submitted.

Comment: Thank you all i understand what was wrong with the 2 last errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the `xhr` variable is undefined. With a quick glance at the `getResponse` function you can see that it's probably not in scope. The one that is a parameter to `AjaxLoad` is local to that function (btw, having it as a parameter seems pretty useless as the first thing you do is assigning to it), and the one which your passing as an argument in your invocation is probably `undefined` or from a different scope.

Instead, you can access the current `XMLHttpRequest` object from the event handler with the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Change your code to

```
if (this.responseText == "0"){
```

Comment: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length" register.php:1
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Comment: Are those PHP errors? Then you'd have to show us that source. However, you seldom have to set the `ContentLength` header manually, it is computed dynamically and automatically set.

Comment: The captcha code is now working, I see what you mean i will try to see whats wrong with the php but do you sure its php errors? and mabye you know what can couse this errors?

Comment: Well, as the source file is `register.php` I guessed they were PHP errors. How did you get them? Were they logged in the browser console, were they in the server response?

Comment: No, those are javascript errors. The webpage just happens to be called "register.php". The problem is - you are _not allowed_ to set the `Content-length` and `Connection` from javascript - presumably for security reasons.

Comment: @Eric: Oh, you're right. Didn't see they were part of that `headers` object literal. [They are supposed](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader) to be set by the UA.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use ajax and have jQuery, use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [friends](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/):

```
$.post(
    "../php/Ajax/captchaValidator.php",
    userCap.attr("name") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(userCap.val()),
    function(responseData) {
        //...
    }
)
```

---

Your code doesn't work because the variable `xhr` is not in the scope of `getResponse`. You can use `this` inside the event handler instead of `xhr` to refer to the XHR object.

Comment: I am not trying to use any ajax with jquery, The code did worked before i dont know what i have changed.

Comment: @uBlankText: Therein lies your problem. If you're using jQuery anyway, you should be trying to do ajax through it.

Comment: I do understand you, But do you really think my problem is that i am not using ajax although it did worked before without jquery ajax?

Comment: You're problem is that you're trying to reinvent the wheel, and your new version is broken. While you can spend time fixing your broken wheel, you'd do better to use the tried and tested one.

Comment: And about the link i will take a look at the shorthand methods.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the reason your code did not work

Comment: The problem cant be the scope i did try.